# Selenium VBA - find row name from element id

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

Trying to extract data from this weblink https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/u/BBL/2108803/bs.html

I am able to get to the specific cells I'm after eg aj_1_7_shirtNumber, aj_1_7_name etc

Each link lives in either a row that is either "player-row aj_1 p_starter" or "player-row aj_1 p_notstarter", but I cannot work out how to differentiate the two.

I have previously used the table number within Xpath but have found this changes from time to time so wanted to use the aj_1_7_name as this is consistent but I need to know if it sits in "player-row aj_1 p_starter" or "player-row aj_1 p_notstarter"

```
        Set MyVal = ch.FindElementById("aj_1_7_shirtNumber")
        Sht.Cells(1, 1) = MyVal.Text
```

This gets the value I want, but I need a flag of "player-row aj_1 p_starter" or "player-row aj_1 p_notstarter"

Comment: Add an initial search for the class "on-court" and then use that object to get the List of players using  FindElementsByID("aj_1_7_shirtNumber").

Comment: Thanks @igittr I couldn't quite get what you suggested to work, I think because the '7' changes for each player, but it led me to a slightly different solution that does what I needed. Much appreciated

Comment: Easy enough but depends how you will use this when writing to sheet. What should result look like?